# What is this WW1 era plane?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

I'm trying to identify this plane from an old family photograph.  Is it possibly  a DH4?
[image: photo]

The tail number doesn't bring any success (well, at least not that I can find).
Any info would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any landing you can walk away from, eh?

Comment: We need a bit more info. Which country? What year? Any specific location?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [worldmilitair.com](http://www.worldmilitair.com/serials/countries/uk/uni%20020%200204.pdf) (.pdf), serial E8557 was assigned to an [Airco DH.9A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.9A), a light bomber used by the newly formed Royal Air Force starting in the final months of World War 1.

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airco_D.H.9A_ExCC.jpg)</sup>